# doctrine 2: how to use datatype long?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, long-integer, sqldatatypes

in Java I have a `long` value that I send to the server and I want to store it per Symfony2 / Doctrine2 in a mysql db.

PHP_INT_MAX might only be 2147483647 (different systems, might be 32bit only) and in MySql I think BIGINT should be used.

What's the best way for accomplishing that, can someone provide an example entity-declaration?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the data types in Doctrine in here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

There is `bigint` type that you can use:

```
bigint: Type that maps a database BIGINT to a PHP string.
```